# Flickering and flashing laptop screen during charging

Tags: laptop, display, power

I have a Lenovo Flex 14 that has started exhibiting some unusual behaviour during charging - when the screen is blank (regardless of whether the laptop is on or fully powered down) the bottom right of the screen will flicker with pulses of light, which sometimes become bright flashes that fill the entire screen.

The screen appears fine when it's on (awake and outputting something) so I'm guessing this could be a power supply issue? I've never encountered anything like this before so help troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A screen that flashes with light when the laptop is fully off would be a hardware problem

Comment: @John agreed. Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: If what I said above is true, you need to take it to a repair service to fix the hardware.